# Зависает программа при длительном рисовании (WinAPI/C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

[Ссылка на проект](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VdB7U1tSKbHtFPo9GKzcY5RQQ9YRCJBa/view?usp=sharing)

Решил написать простой Paint, чтоб вникнуть в WinAPI. В итоге если рисовать более 20 секунд, то все зависает и меню сверху исчезает. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина проста - исчерпание ресурсов. Карандаш (pen) Вы создаете, причем на каждый чих, а удалять их не удаляете. Читайте [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd183509(v=vs.85).aspx) и вызывайте DeleteObject.

В целом, если создать 10000 дескрипторов, то они "кончатся" и дальше будет зависание или падение.

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал ручку глобальной, теперь все работает)